# jQuery - Show/Hide Elements on certain date & time?

Tags: jquery

So I've been challenged with the task of "stunting" events.  I'm very new to jQuery, so I'm kind of learning on the go.  I said I'd give it my best shot and after Googling around I think I've made a start but I have no idea on how to continue.  So here I am to call for help! :)

**Here's what's been requested:**

The User wants the ability to

- Set Start Date   *[DD/MM/YYYY]*
- Set End Date
- Set Start Time   *[HH:MM]*
- Set End Time
- Add The URL
- Add New BG Image Path

**So the end result would be something like:**

- Before Start Date - [Original Banner]
- Start Date to End Date - [Stunt Banner]
- After End Date - [Original Banner]

I kind of get what I need to do, and I think I've made a start - But I'm certain I've got my code mixed up and in the wrong places!

Any direction would be great!

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/sfe0hs4v/1/

Here's the list of Variables I'd like the end user to be able to change:

```
var target = $('#stuntEvent');
var startDate = "04/10/2014";
var startTime = "09:00";
var endDate = "06/10/2014";
var endTime = "08:59";
var url = "http://www.google.co.uk";
var bgImg = "http://i.imgur.com/npe3PKm.gif";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do it with jQuery? First thing I can think of is that you will load the background image 2 times- original banner will load every time and then on the start-end date you will change it's src and load the stunt banner image. So you better do this on the server side and serve the image as needed :)'

Comment: This would make my life a lot easier too, but I don't have any access to d this server side.  Which is why I need to do it this way!  THanks

Comment: Why would the user be able to change when a particular event is to be displayed ? Did you mean the administrator ? Besides, if you have no access to do this server side, your hands are tied, because you'll need the server to somehow give the front side some information about how a given events is to be displayed.

Comment: Sorry, by end user I just mean a member of the team who has the access to modify the code to display the necessary event.  In terms of the way it's going to be displayed, it would be displayed exactly how it was previously displayed.  All that really needs to happen is on a certain date the bgimage and link need to change.  I'm sure this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have done something, I don't know if it's what you expect. The thing is to use the HTML5 data types to pass information to your JS script, such as the starting/ending date and time of your event, your url and background url. This implies to be able to edit the way your events are printed into your page so you can incorporate those elements.

```js
(function ($) {
    function stuntEvent(target) {
        var startDate = new Date(target.data("start-date")),
            endDate = new Date(target.data("end-date")),
            url = target.data("href"),
            bgImg = target.data("bg-img");

        if (startDate <= fullDate && fullDate <= endDate) {
            target.prop('href', url);
            target.css({"background": "url(" + bgImg + ") center no-repeat #fff"});
        }
    }

    var fullDate = new Date();
    stuntEvent($('#stuntEvent'));
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}
#stuntEvent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/eWoIOYD.gif') center no-repeat #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="stuntEvent" data-start-date="10/04/2014 14:00" data-end-date="10/06/2014 17:00" data-bg-img="http://i.imgur.com/npe3PKm.gif" data-href="http://www.google.co.uk"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This is the result that I expect to see, however, we're still catering for early browsers, like IE7/8 and I'm unsure if this will work?  That's why I initially tried a jQuery approach.  Thanks again!

Comment: This is using jQuery, the method `.data()` is in jQuery. So this shouldn't be a problem for older browsers, jQuery does a good job with the compatibility. Also, remember to accept this as the answer to your question.